# How to bind and save an object containing a list of objects to database context in ASP.NET MVC with EF code first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I was trying to build a model as follows (assume the syntax is alright). I wanted to know how to bind and save an object that contains list of objects. For eg. in the following code, I want to save an object of type `SchoolGrade` to the database (it works fine if it does not contain `List<Chapter>` or create a separate dbset for `Chapter` and link by Id).

The `SchoolGrade` object has 2 lists of the type `List<Chapter>`, one for physics and another for math. Assuming I am populating the list correctly for physics and math, I am not sure how to save the context as a whole for `SchoolGrade` which includes both the lists.

**Note:** I am using 2 `List<Chapter>` instead of having one `List<Chapter>` and having a type in the `Chapter` class because, I want to dynamically add and remove chapters for physics and math in different sections of HTML to keep a clean design.

Code snippet:

```
namespace School.Models
{
     public class SchoolGrade
     {
         public Guid SchoolGradeID {get; set;}
         public string SchoolGradeName {get; set;} //eg. 8th Grade
         public List<Chapter> Physics {get; set;} //eg. List of chapters for physics course
         public List<Chapter> Maths {get; set;} //eg. List of chapters for maths course
         public SchoolGrade()
         {
             Physics = new List<Chapter>();
             Maths = new List<Chapter>();
         }
     }

     public class Chapter
     {
         public string ChapterName {get; set;}
         public string ChapterContent {get; set;}
     }
}

namespace School.Controllers
{
     public class SchoolGradesController : Controller
     {
        private SchoolGradeContext db = new SchoolGradeContext();
     }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
          var schoolGrade = new SchoolGrade();
          return View(job);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(SchoolGrade schoolGrade)
     {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
                db.SchoolGrades.Add(schoolGrade);
                db.SaveChanges();
          }
          return View(schoolGrade);
     }
}

namespace School.DAL
{
     public class SchoolGradeContext : DbContext
     {
           public PipelineContext() : base("PipelineContext")
           {

           }
           public DbSet<SchoolGrade> SchoolGrades { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Could you please point out the best way to go about following design? I tried browsing many topics relating to this but none had provided any context regarding saving the changes to a db (without using a separate dbset).

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather consider involving inheritance in your design, having just one collection of `Chapters` on `SchoolGrade` results in cleaner design (you don't need to add a new property for each new `Chapter`) and you will get rid of problems regarding mapping with EF.

```
public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class PhysicsChapter : Chapter
{
    ...
}

public class MathsChapter : Chapter
{
    ...
}

public class SchoolGrade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class SchoolGradeContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolGradeContext() : base("SchoolGradeContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SchoolGrade> SchoolGrades { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().Map<PhysicsChapter>(m => m.Requires("ChapterTypeId").HasValue(1));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().Map<MathsChapter>(m => m.Requires("ChapterTypeId").HasValue(2));
    }
}
```

Which would require having some discriminator column `ChapterTypeId` on your `Chapter` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the ForeignKey attribute on the Chapter class with a field to carry the SchoolGradeId.

For example:

```
public class Chapter
 {
     public string ChapterName {get; set;}
     public string ChapterContent {get; set;}

     [ForeignKey("SchoolGrade")]
     public Guid SchoolGradeID {get; set;}
 }
```